# how to fix the while loop in server.c and client.c

Tags: c

server.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void error(char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(1);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     int sockfd, newsockfd, portno, clilen;
     char buffer[256];
     struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
     int n;
     char *result1 = "Ian G. Harris";
     char *result2 = "Joe Smith";
     char *result3 = "Jane Smith";
     if (argc < 2) 
     {
         fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no port provided\n");
         exit(1);
     }
     sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
     if (sockfd < 0) 
     {
        error("ERROR opening socket");
     }
     bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
     portno = atoi(argv[1]);
     serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
     serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
     serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
     if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,
              sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) 
              error("ERROR on binding");
     listen(sockfd,5);
     clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);
     newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);
     if (newsockfd < 0) 
     {
          error("ERROR on accept");
     }
     while (strcmp(buffer, "+++") != 0)
     {
         bzero(buffer,256);
         n = read(newsockfd,buffer,255);
         if (n < 0) error("ERROR reading from socket");
         printf("Address server started\n");
         if (strcmp(buffer, "harris@ics.uci.edu\n") == 0)
         {
             printf("%s\n", result1);
         }
         else if(strcmp(buffer, "joe@cnn.com\n") == 0)
         {
              printf("%s\n", result2);
         }
         else if(strcmp(buffer, "jane@slashdot.org\n")==0)
         {
             printf("%s\n", result3);
         }
     }
     return 0; 
}
```

client.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void error(char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(0);
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sockfd, portno, n;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    struct hostent *server;

    char buffer[256];
    if (argc < 3) 
    {
           fprintf(stderr,"usage %s hostname port\n", argv[0]);
           exit(0);
    }
    portno = atoi(argv[2]);
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd < 0) 
        error("ERROR opening socket");
    server = gethostbyname(argv[1]);
    if (server == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no such host\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    bcopy((char *)server->h_addr, 
         (char *)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,
         server->h_length);
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
    if (connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) 
        error("ERROR connecting");
    while (strcmp(buffer, "+++") != 0)
    {
        printf("> ");
        bzero(buffer,256);
        fgets(buffer,255,stdin);
        n = write(sockfd,buffer,strlen(buffer));
        if (n < 0) 
             error("ERROR writing to socket");
        bzero(buffer,256);
        n = read(sockfd,buffer,255);
        if (n < 0) 
             error("ERROR reading from socket");
        printf("%s\n",buffer);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am new to c and I am writing a server.c and client.c. The problem of my code is that I cannot make the program keep taking inputs until I enter "+++" to quit. The correct output is shown below:

client terminal:

```
> harris@ics.uci.edu
Ian G. Harris
> joe@cnn.com
Joe
>
```

server terminal:

```
Address server started
harris@ics.uci.edu
joe@cnn.com
```

in my code, when I enter "harris@ics.uci.edu" in client terminal, it does the following:

```
> harris@ics.uci.edu
(empty line)
```

and it does not take any input anymore.

Is there something wrong in the while loop? can someone help me to fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: or ease of readability and understanding: 1) follow the axiom: only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement. 2) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via one blank line. 3) separate functions by 2 or 3 blank lines (be consistent)

Comment: when the wrong number of parameters provided, the code should put out a 'usage' statement similar to: `fprintf( stderr, "USAGE: %s <portNum>\n, argv[0] )`

Comment: the function: `htons()` is expecting a uint16_t parameter, not a int parameter.

Comment: the function: `listen()` has a returned value, that should be checked to assure the operation was successful

Comment: when the call to `read()` returns an error condition, do not continue in the program and certainly do not be comparing the input buffer to anything.

Comment: the posted code contains several 'magic' numbers. 'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis. (I.E. 255, 256) 'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, maintain. Strongly suggest using a `enum` statement or `#define` statements to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names, then use those meaningful names through out the code.

Comment: this line, `while (strcmp(buffer, "+++") != 0)` at least on the first pass through the loop, is not set via a call to read(). Suggest basing the loop on the results of a call to read() rather than on the contents of the buffer.

Comment: when compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings. (for gcc at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` I also use: `-Wconversion -std=gnu11` )

Comment: when calling `fgets()` the length should be the full length of the input buffer, not one less than the length of the input buffer.  Also, the `fgets()` will include the newline sequence for best results, the code should search the input buffer for a '\n' and overlay that char with a NUL byte

Comment: if the call to `write()` returns an error condition, then the other computer will not have received the message, so do not be calling `read()`, expecting the other computer to send a response.

Comment: when communicating via a `socket` it is best to not use low level functions like `read()` and `write()` best to use high level functions like `send()` and `recv()` as they will handle a lot of the error checking

Comment: when writing a server, it is best to not delay other client communications by processing the communications within the main thread.  Much better to 1) have previously created a `thread pool`  then 2) pass each client processing to the the next available thread

Comment: this line: `while (strcmp(buffer, "+++") != 0)` will fail to catch the final communication because the user entered the `+++` which was entered via a newline and when using `fgets()` that new line will also be in the input buffer so this will never match.

Answer (score 1):

Few things:

In the client loop, you do a `write` and a `read` on the socket. But your server never writes to that socket(no `write` call in the server, only `read`). As a result, your client gets blocked on the `read` call. That's why you cannot enter more...

In general, you need to check how much you wrote in and keep writing until done (a loop is needed).

```
int n = 0;
while (n != strlen(buffer){
   n += write(sockfd,&buffer[n],strlen(buffer)-n);      
}
```

Same goes for reading from a socket:

```
int n = 0;
while (n != strlen(buffer){
   n += read(sockfd,&buffer[n],strlen(buffer)-n);      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I believe is likely happening.

1. Client sends some chunk of data. Possibly all of the string `harris@ics.uci.edu`, but possibly less.
2. The server reads some chunk of this, most likely less than the full string, say `harris@ic`.
3. The server performs the `strcmp`, which doesn't match anything, so returns to the top of the loop.
4. The server reads the remainder of the email, say `s.uci.edu` *into `buffer`, thus overwriting it*.
5. Again, this doesn't match anything, so the server goes to the top of the while loop again.
6. The server hangs on the `read` call, waiting for data from the client. Because the client is waiting for a reply, it's stuck on its own `read` call. ...And nothing else happens.

There are two main problems here. First, TCP sockets are just streams of bytes, and when you read data from them, the OS no longer keeps it around. You are now expected to handle any previously- or partially-read data if you need. And second, the OS often transmits (both sending and receiving) fewer bytes than you request. While you ask that the full string `harris@ics.uci.edu` be sent, only a portion of that may be sent, or only a portion of that may be read on the other side.

This means two things for you. It's always important to check the amount of data read/written any time you call `read(2)` or `write(2)`, but it's *crucial* in networking. Make sure you read/write as much as you need (the full email in this case) before moving on to, for example, waiting for a reply.

The second thing is that you need some way of delineating full messages and buffering partial messages. In what you've got, as is common in lots of text-based messaging protocols, the newline `\n` is your delimiter. So instead of a single call to `read(2)` in the server, you need something like this (pseduocode):

```
while newline not in data:
    data += read(sockfd, ...)
```

Once you receive your newline, process the full message, but don't throw away any extra bytes you've read from the next message. Keep those around, and append the next bytes read from the socket to them, and so on.

EDIT:

Note that it's usually better to use `recv(2)` and `send(2)` when working with sockets. The `read(2)`/`write(2)` system calls will work just fine, but the others are more clear when working with sockets, and allow you to specify other flags, for example, peeking at the bytes currently on the socket or waiting until all the bytes you request are available before returning.