# How to keep the server on?

Tags: c

In c, how do I keep the server on when I close the client? (assume the server only handles 1 client at a time ).

I did something like this:

server.c

```
while(1)
{
    newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);
    while ((strcmp(buffer, "quit\n") != 0)
    {
        .....
    }
    close(newsockfd);
}
```

my idea is, when the client receives the "quit" command, it sends it to the server, and when the server gets it, the second loop breaks. And it waits for the next client. My first connection works fine, but the second connection does not work. Can someone explain why? Or is there a better way to do that?

Specific examples would be better. Thanks in advance.

Comment: two `while(1)` loops.

Comment: at first glance, i think what you have _should_ work. i'm assuming you have a `bind` and `listen` before the `while` loop, right?

Comment: well, i'd clear buffer before reconnecting too.

Comment: yes, but in the second connection, it seems that the server dose not get what the client sends.

Comment: ^ good point re: the buffer! is the program _exiting_?

Comment: No, the program should not exit unless I type "Ctrl-c"

Comment: No, no, @zhangdi -- we mean, "What is the _observed_ behavior?" We know the _desired_ behavior, but it sounds like the server _is_ accepting connections after the first, but _because_ the buffer isn't being cleared, it is immediately closing them.

Comment: That is, the buffer _starts_ with `"quit\n"` in it.

Comment: There are two `while` loops, as @MDXF said, maybe you still in the outer loop. Is this a typo?

Comment: no, @haolly - the inner loop is "do this until the user types quit" and the outer is "keep accepting new connections forever". that's correct.

Comment: @RobStarling I meas this `while (while (strcmp(buffer, "quit\n") != 0)` has two while statement, does it right?

Comment: OH - i didn't even _see_ that. yes. :)

Comment: @RobStarling can you tell me how do I clear the buffer?

Comment: i answered! see below.

Comment: Also, good job writing a shorter, more-specific question than your previous version of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42682646/how-to-fix-the-while-loop-in-server-c-and-client-c -- that said, it looks from that question like you knew how to use `bzero` to clear the buffer...  (Is this one also you, or someone else working on the same problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42709410/how-to-make-the-server-keep-responding-to-requests-until-its-process-is-killed-b )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(okay, the comments have gone on too long...)

Clear `buffer` before the inner `while` loop:

```
// ... setup, including bind listen ...
while(1)
{
    newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);
    buffer[0] = 0; /* very important so we don't see data from previous clients */
    while ((strcmp(buffer, "quit\n") != 0)
    {
        .....
    }
    close(newsockfd);
}
// ... shutdown, including close(sockfd)
```

Comment: Thanks, that helps

Comment: great! you will probably also need to clear the buffer repeatedly _inside_ the inner `while` loop if you want "quit" to work when it's not the first thing a client sends.

Comment: you might also want to change your check to be "while `buffer` does not _start_ with "quit\n"", like `while (strncmp(buffer, "quit\n", 5) != 0)` -- that way if a client sends "quit\nMore information..." you still exit correctly.

Answer (score 0):

before looping back to the top of the `while(1)` loop, clear the `buffer[]` to all NUL bytes, perhaps by:

```
memset( buffer, '\0', sizeof( buffer ) );
```

other wise, the "quit\n" is still in the `buffer` so the code will never process the second (and later) clients